# Facebook Account Kit didn't get sms code from US number

Tags: objective-c, account-kit

I'm using Facebook Account Kit in my iOS app. Everything works good for me and my internal testers (Israel). But AppStore external testers can't get the sms verification code from account kit. Does anyone saw problem like this? And how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, my app started being rejected because of this issue, the reviewer is from the US. Did you find any solutions? It was normally approved, but the App Store reviewer has been saying that my app cannot login because they did not receive SMS. This only happens after the 10.3.2 rollout. I am not sure if it is related.

Comment: I thought it was an isolated issue, but it turns out that you have this problem too, I can receive SMS in my country (Indonesia), but the App Store reviewer kept saying they don't receive SMS to login.

Comment: I've changed in the facebook developer account kit from dev mode to public mode and its worked

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem because ours is already in public mode

Comment: did you find a solution ?!!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Facing a similar problem now

Comment: Similar issue, any solutions?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?